# C++, how to remove char from a string

Tags: c++, string, loops, char

I have to remove some chars from a string, but I have some problems. I found this part of code online, but it does not work so well, it removes the chars but it even removes the white spaces

```
string messaggio = "{Questo e' un messaggio} ";
    char chars[] = {'Ì', '\x1','\"','{', '}',':'};
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
    {
        messaggio.erase(remove(messaggio.begin(), messaggio.end(), chars[i]), messaggio.end());
    }
```

Can someone tell me how this part of code works and why it even removes the white spaces?

Comment: please post  a [mcve] including includes and all needed to reproduce your output. I could not get this to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/5Kqj4xvjK

Comment: what characters do you need to remove? There is no `Ì` or `:` or `"` in the string, and I don't know what `\x1` is.

Comment: I think `\x1` is for control values, i. e., when you press a button with control pressed. It is displayed in many IDEs, like Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, @SolvedGames it is for control values... Can you tell me how this `messaggio.erase(remove(messaggio.begin(), messaggio.end(), chars[i]), messaggio.end());` works?

Comment: `'Ì'` idicates you have non ASCII characters. This means that you have to handle encoding. If your program uses mutibyte encoding (like UTF-8) this thing becomes much more complex. So pleas specify your problem more carefully.

Comment: Is this WIndows platform? If yes what is the locale?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `strlen` on your `chars` array. This function stops ONLY when it encounters a `\0`, and you inserted none... So you're parsing memory after your array - which is bad, it should even provoke a SEGFAULT.
Also, calling `std::remove` is enough.

A correction could be:

```
    char chars[] = {'I', '\x1','\"','{', '}',':'};
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(chars); ++i)
    {
        std::remove(messaggio.begin(), messaggio.end(), chars[i]) ;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively: `for (char c : chars)`

Comment: `std::remove` just moves the characters in the string, it doesn't remove them, you need to call `erase` to remove the unused characters at the end of the string

Comment: " should SEGFAULT" - more accurately, could SEGFAULT. Another very real possibility is that the CPU reads some junk and finds a stray `\0` byte somewhere before SEGFAULT'ing. Or the optimizer may just decide that the code must be unreachable and remove it altogether. Undefined Behavior has many, many forms.

Comment: @MSalters "Should" in a perfect world, where everything is perfectly shielded against buffer overruns... In real world, hey, just need faith to find a `\0` quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Wissblade is more or less correct, it just lacks of some technical details.

As mentioned `strlen` searches for terminating character: `'\0'`.
Since `chars` do not contain such character, this code invokes "Undefined behavior" (buffer overflow).
"Undefined behavior" - means anything can happen, code may work, may crash, may give invalid results.

So first step is to drop `strlen` and use different means to get size of the array.

There is also another problem. Your code uses none ASCII character: `'Ì'`.

I assume that you are using Windows and Visual Studio. By default `msvc` compiler assumes that file is encoded using your system locale and uses same locale to generate exactable. Windows by default uses single byte encoding specific to your language (to be compatible with very old software). Only in such chase you code has chance to work. On platforms/configuration with mutibyte encoding, like `UTF-8` this code can't work even after `Wisblade` fixes.

`Wisblade` fix can take this form (note I change order of loops, now iteration over characters to remove is internal loop):

```cpp
bool isCharToRemove(char ch)
{
    constexpr char skipChars[] = {'Ì', '\x1','\"','{', '}',':'};
    return std::find(std::begin(skipChars), std::end(skipChars), ch) != std::end(skipChars);
}

std::string removeMagicChars(std::string message)
{
    message.erase(
        std::remove_if(message.begin(), message.end(), isCharToRemove),
        message.end());
    }
    return message;
}
```

Let me know if you need solution which can handle more complex text encoding.